# White noise in Lie group

Tags: stochastic-calculus

The matter is in the title.

Is there a means to define the white noise process in Lie group. A basic definition 
[link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64205/ergodicity-of-convoluted-white-noise)

**Question:**
Can we replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a Lie group?

---

In fact, I would like for studying  the stochastic differential equation

\begin{align}
 X_t^{x} &=x + \sum_{k=1}^m \int_0^t \mathcal{X}_k
(X_s^{x}) dB^k_s  & ( *)
\end{align}

For   $H > \frac{1}{2}$,

1. $\mathcal{X}_k$'s are $C^{\infty}$-bounded vector fields on
   $\mathbb{R}^m$ which I would like to remplace it by a lie group $G$.
2. $B$ is a $m$-dimensional fractional Brownian motion  taking its values ​​in $G$.

In Hida space $\mathcal{S}^*$, equation (*) becomes
$$
 d X_t^{x} =\sum_{k=1}^m  \mathcal{X}_k
(X_t^{x})\diamondsuit B^k_t dt \qquad (**) 
$$
whith $X_0^x=x$. In order to exploit the  underlying Lie algebra should be established white noise on the Lie group.

---

Thanks having taken bother to read this post.

Comment: See Rogers and Williams, vol. 2

Comment: I'll second Steve Huntsman's comment. But, what is H?

Comment: $H\in ]\frac{1}{2}, 1[$

Comment: @alabair: ok, so that is the range of values that H can take. But, you never said what H means. Is it the Hurst index of fractional Brownian motion? So the question is a bit more complicated than just regular Brownian motion, and is not covered by Rogers and Williams. If you're asking about fractional Brownian motion on a Lie group, does that mean that you are already familiar with regular BM and stochastic differential equations on the group? Also, why specifically $H > 1/2$? Have I understood you correctly? I think the question should provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

We can define fractional Brownian motion in Lie groups when $H>1/4$ by using the Lyons' rough paths theory

[Self-similarity and fractional Brownian motion on Lie groups](http://ejp.ejpecp.org/article/view/530)